# How to insert mongodb insert timestamp instead of jmeter client timestamp while inserting document from jmeter

Tags: java, mongodb, jmeter

I have a sample java code as below in jmeter to insert a record and I am trying to insert the document with the mongo db insert timestamp when the record is inserted from the jmeter, but when I insert the **time** as below it is printing jmeter client timestamp instead of mongo db timestamp.

`Date date= new Date(); long time = date.getTime();`

I have modified the java code and appended  **.append("documentInsertTime", Updates.currentDate("timestamp"))** to insert mongodb time stamp but when the document is inserted i am getting like this

`"documentUpdateTime": {"$currentDate": {"timestamp": true}`

Below is my full java code in jmeter.

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import org.bson.Document;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Updates;



try {
MongoCollection<Document> collection = vars.getObject("collection");
ArrayList items = new ArrayList<Document>();
Date date= new Date();
 
long time = date.getTime();
 
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(time);

for(int i in 0..99){
Document item = new Document("_id",i).append("category","calibration").append("instanceId","string1").append("alertCode",0).append("code","string5").append("JmeterClientCurrentDate", time);
items.add(item);
}
Document document = new Document("deviceId","${deviceId}")
.append("documentInsertTime", Updates.currentDate("timestamp"))
.append("shadowName","alerts")
.append("shadowDocument",new Document("state",new Document("reported",new Document("cdmData",new Document("items",items)))))
.append("_class","com.hp.stratus.iotmesh.mongodb.DeviceShadow");
collection.insertOne(document);
return "Document inserted";
}
catch (Exception e) {
SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Exception: " + e);
}
```

Could someone please help me to modify this code to insert the mongo db insert timestamp while running this script

Comment: change `${deviceId}` syntax to `vars.get("deviceId")`

Comment: Device id I am passing as argument so no issue with respect to that . I want how to modify above code to  insert  mongo db timestamp

Comment: Would changing `.append("documentInsertTime", Updates.currentDate("timestamp"))` to 
`.append("documentInsertTime", Updates.currentDate(new Date()))`

Comment: I tried changing to what you have suggested i am getting this error "Response message:Exception: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.mongodb.client.model.Updates.currentDate() is applicable for argument types: (Date) values: [Mon Nov 22 15:14:45 IST 2021]
Possible solutions: currentDate(java.lang.String)"

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use [BSONTimestamp](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/org/bson/types/BSONTimestamp.html) instead of your [Timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) class

Or just go for `new Date()`

More information on MongoDB testing with JMeter: [MongoDB Performance Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance-testing-with-jmeter)

Comment: But if I go for new Date will it not insert jmeter client date instead of mongo db insert date ? when i execute the abov mongo script